# Opening more pipes over Paramiko Channel

Tags: python, ssh, pipe, paramiko

When connecting to a ssh server via Paramiko, reading the stdios is very easy when using `SSHClient`.

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('127.0.0.1', username='rusername', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
```

I can access the used `Channel` via `client.get_transport()._channels` (maybe there is better way?)

Is it possible to open more pipes over this channel?  I am calling a Python script on the ssh server so I can open the fd in the server side script for writing.

`Channel.makefile()` doesn't seem to correlate to another pipe/fd in the little testing I've done. I might be misunderstanding the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To open a file (for reading or writing) on the remote server you can use `open_sftp`:

```
sftp = client.open_sftp()
with sftp.open("/tmp/somefile", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("my data")
```

Comment: This could likely be helpful if I create a named pipe on the server, I could likely read it on the client via your example and write to it from the server code... I was just hoping for a more streamlined method.